# Meta name 'mode' in HTML

Tags: html, tags, mode

Revisiting the HTML code I've found interesting tag:

```
<meta name="mode" content="full" />
```

Does anynody know what the mode full could stand for?

Rescale to full view on portable devices?

Answer (score 1):

**`name attribute`** specifies the **`name of meta content`**.

**`content attribute`** specifies the list of values that are associate with **`name attribute`**.

Check this guide of valid name **[Meta Documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/meta#HTML_Attributes)**

So as per my knowledge is `name=mode` and `content=full` is not valid name in HTML. May be this is currently Drafted in upcoming HTML version.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be such value possible.

I tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta name="mode" content="full" />
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

into the [W3C HTML5 validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and it throws it as an error.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) for possible values for the `<meta>` tag.

Comment: Please DO NOT confuse W3Schools with W3C.... the are not associated at all. To your credit that is the correct validator from W3C. Please see: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Yeah that was a big mistake on my part but I believe my answer was still appropriate, should have been edited instead of downvoted.